# iOS: Handle remote-control events and then relay the events to music apps

Tags: ios, audio, remote-control

I'd like to handle remove control events in my app, but also would like the event can be passed on to other apps when I'm done.

I cannot find clear instructions in Apple's Remote Control Events doc section:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7-SW3

Here it says:

> iOS converts commands into UIEvent objects and delivers the events to
>   an app. The app sends them to the first responder and, if the first
>   responder doesn’t handle them, they travel up the responder chain. For
>   more information about the responder chain, see “The Responder Chain
>   Follows a Specific Delivery Path.”

So I thought I'd place

```
[[self nextResponder] remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: receivedEvent];
```

at the end of my event handler method, expecting that after my handler is done, a currently playing music app, e.g., the built-in music player, would be able to receive the event.
But to my surprise, it never did.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call the following methods to begin receiving the events.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

Then in your application delegate you need to listen for the events.

```
-(void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl){
        switch (event.subtype) {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```