# iOS: Can nextResponder be another app?

Tags: ios, first-responder, remote-control, responder-chain

This question is related (inspired) to my previous question:
[iOS: Handle remote-control events and then relay the events to music apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325438/ios-handle-remote-control-events-and-then-relay-the-events-to-music-apps)

My app can become the first responder to remote-control events.
However, I'd like my app to relay the remote-control events to OTHER apps. So my question is is it possible to set nextResponder to objects in another app? From Apple doc:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html
, it seems to me that the responder chain is app-bounded and nothing is mentioned to relay events between apps.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to make other app do something, is to use something called URL Scheme.